# Forge viewer Quality settings

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

As different end users has different hardware, the GPU usage can sometimes be very heavy to calculate for certain devices/computers, and that's why we are looking to add a dropdown in our application that makes the end user able to choose different quality settings for their online 3D designs.

We would want to categorize different values for three different categories (low/medium/high) by switching on/off relevant settings in the viewer through the API.

Our goal is to specify the absolute lowest quality/performance settings for the "low" option, and the absolute best rendering quality for the "high" setting. Here's our suggestion:

**LOW QUALITY**

```
viewer.setOptimizeNavigation(true)
viewer.setQualityLevel(false, false);
viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
```

**MEDIUM QUALITY**

```
viewer.setOptimizeNavigation(false)
viewer.setQualityLevel(true, true);
viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
viewer.setGroundReflection(false);
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(true);
```

**HIGH QUALITY**

```
viewer.setQualityLevel(true, true);
viewer.setGroundShadow(true);
viewer.setGroundReflection(true);
viewer.setProgressiveRendering(false); (to display shaders correctly)
```

Our question is whether there's any comments to the list above, or any other settings we should take into consideration. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Torbjorn, I am not sure how much these option could affect GPU usage, but obviously, setProgressiveRendering(false) will cause performance issue when navigating the model when the model is large. I am checking with our engineer team on your question.

Comment: the comments from our engineer team is posted as an answer. hope it explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setOptimizeNavigation doesn’t matter when both arguments of setQualityLevel are false, since it effectively makes them false while navigating. I would suggest using setOptimizNavigation(true) for the medium quality, and maybe even for the high quality, since it only matters when you are moving the view around. Turning it off can disrupt smooth navigation. It depends on what you think High Quality means.

In addition, obviously, setProgressiveRendering(false) will cause performance issue of navigating the model when the model is large.

Comment: Thanks @Xiaodong. This was great input. We actually experienced high GPU usage in particular when moving the models around and the OptimizeNavigation seemed to be key in order to make the user experience more smooth for the end user.